# sourceModel property in QSortFilterPtoxyModel - Need to understand this code

Tags: c++, qt

I was going over the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) and I came across this example

```
bool MySortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left,
                                       const QModelIndex &right) const
 {
     QVariant leftData = sourceModel()->data(left);
     QVariant rightData = sourceModel()->data(right);

     if (leftData.type() == QVariant::DateTime) {
         return leftData.toDateTime() < rightData.toDateTime();
     } else {
         QRegExp *emailPattern = new QRegExp("([\\w\\.]*@[\\w\\.]*)");

         QString leftString = leftData.toString();
         if(left.column() == 1 && emailPattern->indexIn(leftString) != -1)
             leftString = emailPattern->cap(1);

         QString rightString = rightData.toString();
         if(right.column() == 1 && emailPattern->indexIn(rightString) != -1)
             rightString = emailPattern->cap(1);

         return QString::localeAwareCompare(leftString, rightString) < 0;
     }
 }
```

Although I understand the example I dont get where the `sourceModel` object is declared and where it came from?

Comment: Qt docs say about `sourceModel()` function: "Returns the model that contains the data that is available through the proxy model.". It stored internally in the proxy model.

Comment: Which base class has this object ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar It was declared outside of the `MySorftFilterProxyModel` class. Like in the code snippet little above that one: `MyItemModel *sourceModel = new MyItemModel(this);`, and: `proxyModel->setSourceModel(sourceModel);`

Comment: @Rajeshwar, it is a member of `QAbstractProxyModel`.

Comment: You're leaking the regexp. Just create it on the stack.

Comment: @vahancho could you put that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt docs say about sourceModel() function:

> "Returns the model that contains the data that is available through the proxy model.".

It stored internally in the proxy model and is the member function of QAbstractProxyModel class.